# Filter all non-integers from string and yield vector

Tags: rust

I have an `Into<String>` variable called `t_num`. I'm attempting to filter all non-integers from the string and return a `Vec<usize>` containing a vector of all integers in the string. Here's my attempt:

```
     let filter_vec = t_num.into().chars().
         filter(|a| a.parse::<usize>()).                                                                                      
         collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

The problem is i'm getting the error

```
error: no method named `parse` found for type `&char` in the current scope
       filter(|a| a.parse::<usize>()).
```

so the problem is that char doesn't implement `parse`, is there a method similar to `parse` implemented for `char`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`char` has a [`to_digit`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.char.html#method.to_digit) method that converts a character to the corresponding digit.

```
fn parse_digits(t_num: &str) -> Vec<u32> {
    t_num
        .chars()
        .filter_map(|a| a.to_digit(10))
        .collect()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", parse_digits("123asd456")); // prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
}
```